# dynamic gallery content in android

Tags: android, memory, gallery

In my gallery i want to show lots of pictures, one at a time, but the size of all the pictures taken together, is too large to fit into memory. So I will have to load/unload pictures as the user moves through the gallery. Each view in the gallery consists of a RelativeLayout, containing the picture and a describing text.  Is there a method I could override that gets called each time the gallery view changes?

getView of the corresponding adapter is not suitable, it sometimes does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

How about `onItemSelected()`?

```
this.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    //@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {    

        if(lastSelectedView!=null) {
            ((ImageView)lastSelectedView).setAlpha(100);
        }
        ((ImageView)arg1).setAlpha(255);

        lastSelectedView=arg1;
    }
};
```